# In Hulk (2003) why did David fail to kill his son when he was a baby?

Tags: the-incredible-hulk, marvel, hulk-2003

Very morbid I know. David wanted to kill Bruce when he was a baby but his mother wouldn't let him and in a scuffle, the mother fell on the knife David was about to stab little Bruce with. Why didn't he continue to try and kill him? Was he just so horrified he couldn't move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the [Official Novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345459679). After David Banner accidentally killed his wife, Bruce flew into a rage, attacked his father and fled the house, raising the alarm with the Military Police. Due to his "ahem" condition he was unable to tell the police which direction his mother had left in, something which inadvertently contributed to her death from blood loss.

> *“But she surprised me. It was as if,” and he spoke in a singsong voice, “as if she and the knife merged into one thing. You can’t
>   imagine—” Betty was wide-eyed as he stared at his empty hand. “—the
>   unbearable finality of it, her life, and mine, suspended at the end of
>   my hand. . . .”*
>
> . . . and he flew at his father, who was staring stupefied at the blade, which was still dripping with the blood of his wife, Bruce’s
>   mother, and he remembered at the last moment to bring the knife up,
>   but the boy was upon him then, leaping, knocking the knife clear, and
>   although the monster wasn’t yet unleashed, wasn’t yet anything
>   approaching his full strength, the glimmer of its potential was there,
>   and the father looked into the eyes of the son and knew fear as the
>   boy tore at him like a wildcat, and the boy lost track of his mother,
>   saw her stumble in shock and confusion out the front door, and then
>   his father tried to throw him down so he could get at the knife . . .
>   and . . .
>
> *“And in that one moment, I took everything that was dear to me . . .”*
>
> . . . he sank his teeth—like an animal, like a berserk, rabid dog—into his father’s neck, and tasted his father’s blood between his
>   teeth, and the father howled and shrieked and the screams of the
>   father blended and overlapped with the howling of sirens . . .
>
> *“. . . and transformed it into nothing more than a memory. . . .”*
>
> . . . as the MPs swarmed the house, and his father was dragged away and shoved into a car with whirling lights atop it, and Bruce was
>   screaming and pointing in the direction he’d seen his mother stagger
>   off, but no one could understand him because he wasn’t speaking, he
>   was grunting and growling inarticulately, like an ape crying out in
>   distress, and someone was trying to hold him steady and he struggled
>   and yanked and shrieked and the rage seized him and his body started
>   to bubble for a moment and someone yelled *“He’s got a swelling here,
>   it’s huge; get some ice packs, stat!”* and *“We need to sedate him; he’s
>   having a seizure!”*

---

In the film, the green explosion in the distance (and Bruce's eyes turning green) are presumably indications that he'd begun to hulk out.

Comment: The film could've done a better job at communicating this, David was been shown taken away in a straight jacket with no wounds and Bruce was standing at the window calmly.

Comment: @Celeritas - Yes. The novel is a hell of a lot better written than the film.